# zoo data looks different when loaded on one machine

Tags: r, macos, zoo

Recently I have been having trouble loading data into R. I have been having this problem using a Mac. On a windows machine the data displays as it should. Most of the time the MAC displays it correctly too but there are certain times it does not.

This is how the data looks on a MAC when I load it in.

`head(trades.zoo)
[1] 14.735 14.735 14.735 14.755 14.735 14.745`

However this is how the data should look. This is how it loads on the Windows machine. This is also how it looks like most of the time on the MAC however randomly it loads as above and I dont know what causes it or how to fix it.

`head(trades.zoo)
                         price quantity    bid bidsize    ask asksize
2014-12-01 00:00:00.220 14.735        1 14.735       3 14.760       4`

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include exactly how you read in your data?

Comment: Sorry about that. I read the data in using load: `filename <-"/Users/abasu/Desktop/filename.zoo.gz"
load(filename)`

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic (using "typographical error" as the reason) as additional answers are unlikely to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out my own problem. I was trying to read a zoo.gz file into R and this is what I was doing:

`filename <-"/Users/abasu/Desktop/filename.zoo.gz"
load(filename)`

However I had not loaded in the zoo package:

`library(zoo)`

So even though the data was getting read and I was not receiving an error message there actually was an error of the zoo library being absent. I think I should have received an error message. Once I loaded the zoo package the data set started working on the Mac. However, I still have no idea why it was working on the windows machine without the zoo package being installed there either.

Comment: Once enough time elapses, you will be able to select this as the correct answer.